# How to center sub elements under a div in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, center

I have looked at the documentation of boostrap 4.

To center the content horizontally we could use **`justify-content-center`** class.

for example

i have 4 sub elements in a div like images and text, i want to center them all at once but its not working using above class. is it achievable?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="content col-12 col-sm-6 d-flex justify-content-center ">
  <div class="photo-wrapper">
    <img src="#" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="text-wrapper">
    <div class="title">
      Title
    </div>
    <div class="position">
      Position
    </div>
    <div class="phones">
      Phone
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6  p-0 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-sm-start">
  <a href="#" class="link-button">See profile</a>
</div>
```

It should look like below image but it doesn't.

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNqmI.jpg)

Comment: Please add all of relevant code. Is there a container? row? Also, clarify the question the content is centered as expected on smaller screens. https://www.codeply.com/go/h91pwT6dWy

Comment: which block is not in center, may i know? because it working...

Comment: So you need See profile button in center or what? If yes then why are you using justify-content-sm-start class there too? It overrides the center property.

Comment: @Shubham in my case only button is centered

Comment: @Themes.guide I added Container and row, but the it is not centered here is my code https://codeshare.io/5Mynj3 what's missing here? here is the result i got check in smaller devices http://realbusinessanalytics.com/management-scholars-academy/ . Here is the screenshot https://prnt.sc/kfy6df. I need all items to be centered

Comment: mx-auto text-center on your content div ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it in a row class, for instance:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
     <div class="col-md-2"></div>
     <div class="col-md-2"></div>
     <div class="col-md-2"></div>
</div>
```